# How to hide winform or WPF application from "alt+tab" and from task manager's application tab

Tags: wpf, winforms, hide

I saw many questions and answers related to this topic But I didn't find any better solution. Few solution are lengthy and few doesn't work. Now I want to share a nice and easy solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to make application invisible in **WPF**. just add this XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="temp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Minimized" IsTabStop="False" Visibility="Hidden" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Height and width dosn't matter only `Visibility, WindowStyle and ShowInTaskbar` will hide the application from **Alt +Tab** and from task manager's application tab

**Now for Winform:**
Use Form load event and put this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 0; //Declear Opacity = 0 on top
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow; //This is most Important part don't use FormBorderStyle.None or something else
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

This will Hide Winform Application form Alt+tab as well as from task manager's application tab